# how to design frame boundary on camera screen in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

i need your help now i learning Xamarin Forms.

I have one requirement to do this task of camera functionality.design frame boundary on camera.

i have already using this media.plugin to implemented camera in our project.

please help me.

Comment: You can using Xam.Plugin.Media to take photo and video. Refer to the document https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media/. In addition ,don't forget to set  privacies in iOS project and user permissions in Android .

Comment: thanks for suggestion . i have already using this plugin for camera but my requirement is on camera preview want to frame